# Paypal payment type

Tags: paypal

I am looking on adding paypal payment into my website but i am not really sure what exactly i am looking for. I've seen on some websites, like steam, where you can preauthorize your paypal account for any future payments without being redirect back to the paypal.com page.
So, i add a paypal account, i get to the paypal.com page, i approve something and then any future payments are done directly from the website. This is also used on godaddy.

I've researched the paypal documentation a little bit but i did not found the right article. Is it Paypal Billing Agreement?

Thanks,
Radu

Comment: Or is it called "Paypal Future Payments"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are correct . It can be achieved using the Billing Agreements . Here the buyer needs to give you the approval once by logging into his PayPal account during the checkout flow and then at the later time you can charge them for any amount without asking them to go to the checkout flow again . You can refer the below documents for more info :

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-refTrans-SetEC-DoRefTrans-curl-etc/

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/

Comment: So i can use this for any number of transactions in the future? Not just once right?

Comment: Yes , as long as the Billing agreement is active you can use it any number of times . Usually either you can cancel the Billing agreement via API or  Buyer can cancel it from their PayPal Profile .